# Изменение цвета кнопки при нажатии и уменьшение размера поля ввода QLineEdit при обрамлении в Qt Creator 4.8.1 C++

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt5

Пытаюсь написать элементарное окно авторизации (в качестве обучения) и столкнулся со следующей проблемой.
Имеется определенная кнопка в cpp-файле класса:

```
pPB_LogIn = new QPushButton("Log in");
```

Для нее я установил следующие параметры:

```
pPB_LogIn->setStyleSheet("color: white; background-color: rgb(44,168,231)");
```

При нажатии на эту кнопку, она выделяется, и её цвет изменяется на мутно-зеленый и остается таким, что не устраивает. Было бы замечательно если бы её цвет как минимум оставался прежним, а ещё лучше изменялся на другой.
Читал про QPalette, но ничего конкретно для случая с нажатием не нашел (либо просто балбес и читать не умею). Также видел в документации Qt https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html , но примеры с

```
QPushButton{...}
```

не работают (компилятор ругается).
Например, если написать:

```
QPushButton:pressed {
background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
                                  stop: 0 #dadbde, stop: 1 #f6f7fa);}
```

то компилятор выдаст ошибку:

> use of undeclared identifier 'pressed'

К слову, со стилями также есть проблема и в QLineEdit. При добавлении рамки вокруг поля ввода:

```
pLineEdit_Login->setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border: 1px solid grey");
```

само поле уменьшается в размерах:

[image: Кнопка после нажатия на нее и уменьшенное поле ввода]

P.S Работю в Manjaro KDE Linux, Qt creator 4.8.1 Qt 5.12.1(GCC 8.2.1)

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.1 QtCreator 4.8.2 / Qt 5.12.1 (GCC 5.3.1)  работает и через QPushButton::setStyleSheet и через подключение отдельного qss-файла

Comment: И как мне использовать qss файл для описания стиля нажатия на кнопку? В документации я также обнаружил метод focusInEvent. Возможно надо его или ему подобный метод переписать, но я никак не пойму как именно.

Comment: Добавил ответ с примером подгрузки файла стиле

Comment: Может вот это как-то поможет https://forum.manjaro.org/t/qt-application-style-in-gtk-environment/43933

Comment: О, нашел попробуйте через командную строку `<имя приложения> -stylesheet style.qss` Взято отсюда https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/qt#Qt_Style_Sheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте файл (обычно с расширением qss, но это как вам удобно).

В нем пропишите:

```
QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #dadbde, stop: 1 #f6f7fa);
}
```

Далее, этот файл необходимо загрузить и подсунуть в объект приложения:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QFile file("путь/к/файлу/стилей/style.qss");
    if( !file.open(QFile::ReadOnly) )
    {
        // Что-то пошло не так            
    }
    QString styles = QLatin1String(file.readAll());

    // передаем стили в объект приложения
    a.setStyleSheet(styles);

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Написал все также. Сделал вывод в консоли сообщения, если открытие файла не удастся. Программа видит файл, ошибок никаких нет, но нет и никаких изменений. Я правильно понимаю, что присваивание этого стиля объекту QApplication этот стиль присваивается всему приложению в том числе и объекту класса MainWindow? Файл qss разместил в том же месте, что и приложение. Для убедительности прописал абсолютный путь к файлу, начиная от / . Возможно, файл qss нужно добавлять в проект каким-то образом?

Comment: @PunchGott да всему приложению. Попробуте в нем прописать очевидные вещи, например цвет фона чего-нибудь, или что-то в этом роде

Comment: Пробовал написать QLineEdit {color: red}  - никаких изменений. То же самое (то есть ничего) происходит при написании в файле qss QPushButton {background-color: red}

Comment: @PunchGott это все ваш KDE https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uniform_look_for_Qt_and_GTK_applications

Comment: Получается, мне надо использовать Breeze (С английским не очень, чтобы такие статьи читать, максимум - документация Qt) или просто использовать Windows?

Comment: @PunchGott я там добавил комментарий к вашему вопросу. А так да, лучше Windows )

Comment: Перешел на Windows, открыл проект, поиграл немного с тем, как прописать путь. В итоге просто написал `D:/Qt/Projects/messenger/Style.qss` Ошибок также нет, как и результат. В самом файле, чтоб наверняка увидеть результат прописал через SublimeText: `QPushButton {background-color: red}`

Comment: Все, разобрался, написал в main я все правильно, просто не так что-то писал в самом qss файле. То же `QLineEdit {color: red}` прекрасно печатает красными буквами в поле ввода, а вот насчет кнопки надо будет разобраться с синтаксисом. Впредь буду внимательнее. К слову, в Windows эффекта (перекраски цвета) во время нажатии на кнопку нет. С Линуксом буду разбираться, спасибо за помощь!)